# Почему std::isnan() возвращает false для переменной double равной NAN?

Tags: c++, c, qt

Я решил использовать в качестве дефолтного значения параметра функции `NAN`(так же пробовал `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`), но когда попытался проверить его с помощью `std::isnan`, функция вернула `false`. В то же время я выводил значение переменной с помощью `qDebug()` в консоль, где напечаталось значение - `nan`.

Так же пробовал проверить на `NAN` используя правило нанов, которое голасит, что `NAN` всегда не равен `NAN`. Это сработало для неравнества `NAN != NAN`, но не для `x != x`. Во втором случае результат был отрицательный.

Последней попыткой было определение переменной внутри используемой функции со значением `NAN` и проверка ее обоими способами на равенство `NAN`. Результаты те же, `false`.

Совершенно не могу понять в чем может быть дело.

Пример:

```
double abc = NAN;
qDebug()<< abc << (abc != abc) << std::isnan(abc);
```

Вывод:

```
nan false false
```

UPD: Проверил возможность такого использования `NAN` на [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) и там все оказалось хорошо. Пока что думаю, что может быть не так с проектом.

Comment: приведите пжлста пример кода.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov дополнил вопрос примером

Comment: Проверил ваш код в чистом проекте, вывод `nan true true`

Comment: Добавил те же строчки в другой проект - результат правильный. Отпишу о решениии как только найду проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблему вызывает использование `-ffast-math`. Я не знал, что мы используем ее в нашем проекте. Для данной проблемы нет решения, если вы используете `-ffast-math`. Не используйте `NAN` в паре с быстрой математикой.